# How to $setValidity when using ng-if on the same field ? (Angular)

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to use form.form_field.$setValidity on to an ng-if tagged field,
but I get this response when testing out the code,

```
angular.js:13642 TypeError: Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined
```

I think this is because the form field is not yet available by the time I wanted to $setValidity(at the very first $setValidity when ng-if just created the field), does any one know how to solve this problem ? 
Thanks !

(*Pre-condition for this checking to happen right
when ng-if condition passed, is when the text area already contains some inputs, so you can think of it as you input something and switched on/off to hide then show the input text_area field again, the ng-click function on the switch will get triggered and $setValidity happens)

HTML Code

```
    <!-- language: html -->
    <div class="table-switch" ng-click="main.info.switch = !main.info.switch; !main.form.text_area.isEmpty() || main.info.switch || main.validating()">

    <!-- Show this div under ng-if condition -->
    <div ng-if="main.info.switch">
        <!-- Text Area -->
            <textarea name="text_area" ng-model="main.text_area.text" required" ng-change="!main.this_form.text_area.$isEmpty() || main.validating()" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 800, 'blur': 0 } }">
            </textarea>
    </div>
```

Controller Code

```
// This is the function which checks and use $setValidity
$scope.validating = function() {

  $scope.this_form.text_area.$setValidity('validity', false);
  // some API checks then within response/callback set to true if valid

});
```

Reason I am not using ng-show/hide is because I do not want these fields to effect the validity of my form when they are hidden(where I believe ng-show/hide still has the fields and the validity of these fields still effects the validity of the whole form), and I do have a lot of these optional toggled fields.

p.s. This is my first time asking a question here, please let me know anything I can improve when asking questions, thank you !

Comment: Presumably you have access to the `main.info.switch` value within your `$scope.validating` function? In that case, just check that value before setting the field's validity. Something like `if ($scope.main.info.switch) { $scope.this_form.text_area.$setValidity('validity', false); }`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around to this Problem,

Please let me know if there is any other better way to do this,

I set the validity on the form directly, giving unique names,
instead of setting validity directly on to the specific Field.

Since the form is always available when I am working with the fields,
the custom validity are visible as well.

Modified Code

```
// This is the function which checks and use $setValidity
$scope.validating = function() {   

  $scope.this_form.$setValidity('text_area', false);
  // some API checks then within response/callback set to true if valid

});
```